# Incorrect syntax near 'SETS'. - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, grouping-sets

My code:

```
Group BY 
  GROUPING SETS 
  ( 
        (wmsSponsorEntityName), 
        (wmsSponsorEntityPrimaryRegion), 
        (wmsProjectNameSWP) , 
        ()          
  )
```

I'm doing this because those three fields repeat and the other two:

> w.[P2010]
>
> w.wugCounty

differ for some wmsProjectNameSWP

> wmsSponsorEntityName | wmsSponsorEntityPrimaryRegion | wmsProjectNameSWP | w.wugCounty | P2010
>
> ABERNATHY |    O | Local groundwater development | LUBBOCK | 808
>
> ABERNATHY |    O | Local groundwater development | HALE | 2297

But I receive an error of Incorrect syntax near 'SETS'.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add some sample data and expected output for your query. May be you just need `GROUP BY wmsSponsorEntityName, wmsSponsorEntityPrimaryRegion, wmsProjectNameSWP`

Comment: It won't let me paste an image since I don't have 10 reputation yet.

Comment: you can copy the results grid from sql server management studio and paste the results as text in the question itself with the columns

Comment: Thanks. Post is updated.

Answer (score 2):

`GROUPING SETS` was introduced in SQL Server 2008. Which means if you are on SQL Server 2005, you will get a syntax error since it doesn't exist.

Comment: OY. Ok. Thanks, Greg. Everything I found online was saying you could do it. Any other ideas on what I could do?

Comment: Per this URL, you can use combination of UNION ALL and GROUP BY.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a588536-deec-459a-9aaf-f2904daf2236/how-to-use-grouping-sets-in-sql-2005?forum=transactsql.  If you want assistance with a workaround, I suggest posting the complete query.